# Script for the sum of the $j$-th powers of the first $n$ numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a script for the sum of the $j$-th powers of the first $n$ numbers in MATLAB, so:

$s(n,j) = 1+2^j+3^j+\cdots +n^j$

The function should have two inputs so I have started with:

% Sum of the j-th powers of the first n numbers

function z = sumofpowers(n,j)

y=zeros(1,n);
y(1)=1;

for

Then I am stuck on how to actually write this function in MATLAB.

Can someone help?

**EDIT:**

This is my full code:

% Sum of the j-th powers of the first n numbers

function z = sumofpowers(n,j)

y=zeros(1,n);

y(1)=1;

for y=2:n
end

z = sum(y.^j)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y = 1:n;
z = sum(y .^ j)
```

Note that `.^` denotes element-by-element power raising. For example, `[1 3 -2] .^ 2` evaluates to `[1 9 4]`.

Comment: Hmmm, I am trying this: % Sum of the j-th powers of the first n numbers

function z = sumofpowers(n,j)

y=zeros(1,n);
y(1)=1;

for y=2:n  
end

z = sum(y.^j)

Comment: sorry if that is hard to read, I will edit my first post. But this isn't working, say I do "sumofpowers(3,3)" it is just giving me the value of $3^3$

Comment: @Edward I'm pretty sure Adriano's solution should work. What does sum([1:4].^2) give you?

Comment: That gives me the correct answer so I am presuming my script (see original post) is incorrect?

Comment: @Edward If you insist on using a for loop (which isn't very MATLAB like and is not recommended), then you should probably try something like:
    `for k=1:n, y(k) = k; end; z = sum(y.^j)`